# PHP Create a while-loop that subtracts?

Tags: php, while-loop

I got this Exercise : 
Create a while-loop that subtracts 5.23 from the number 526 until the number is between (not equal to) 41 and 51. Answer with the final result as a float, rounded to 2 decimals.

What I doing wrong ?

```
$number = 1;
$sum = 526;
while ($number > 41 && $number < 51)
{
    $sum-=5.23;
    $number++;
}
```

Comment: What are you supposed to output?

Comment: If I'm understanding it right: first issue - your number is assigned 1, which will never satisfy number being greater than 41 and less than 51. So the while loop is bad. And next you don't want to be evaluating the number, you want to be evaluating your sum.

Comment: Your loop never begins execution as 526 is not >41 and <51.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop never actually runs as 1 is never > 41 && < 51

```
$sum = 526;
while (1)
{
    $sum -= 5.23;
    if ( $sum > 41 && $sum < 51 ) { break; }
}
$ANSWER = sprintf('%2.2f', $sum);
echo $ANSWER;
```

Comment: But this only echoes the sum once it is greater than 41? Are the sum and the number the same thing?

Comment: Actually @JayBlanchard it echos the number once if falls below 51, it is subtracting afterall :)

Comment: Right, but is it supposed to be the number, or the sum? From reading the question they do not appear to be the same.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Ok, let me check the question again. I did not getthat

Comment: The question not *quite* clear, that is why I am asking.

Comment: Her is everything what i do and when i run the code i get "3.2 CORRECT. Well done! 50.07"
 * Exercise 3.2 (1 points)
 *
 * Create a while-loop that subtracts 5.23 from the number 526 until the
 * number is between (not equal to) 41 and 51. Answer with the final result as
 * a float, rounded to 2 decimals.
 *
 * Write your code below and put the answer into the variable ANSWER.
 */

 $sum = 526;
 while (1)
 {
     $sum -= 5.23;
     if ( $sum > 41 && $sum < 51 ) { break; }
 }

$ANSWER = round($sum, 3);

Comment: Ah - that is not how you asked the question. @RiggsFolly is right.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Phew, thought that last glass of wine had done for my brain for a second :)

Comment: What was wrong with `while ($sum >= 51) $sum -= 5.23;`? I'm always in favour of less typing, especially after a glass of wine!

Comment: @Nick Nothing as far as I can see

Comment: @RiggsFolly it's ok, it was a rhetorical question or perhaps a poor attempt at humour or possibly both! :)